# Bookmarked table of contents doesn't display sections with Cyrillic titles

Tags: table-of-contents, links, bookmarks, cyrillic

Forum,

When I add a table of contents in my LaTeX document, hyperlink it to the corresponding pages of the document and therefore bookmark it, the bookmarked sections written in the Cyrillic alphabet don't appear at the bookmarked section.

There is the code to demonstrate:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\toccontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\toccontents

\section{Аааа}

\section{Бббб}

\section{Вввв}

\section{Гггг}

\section{Дддд}

\section{Ееее}

\end{document}
```

This creates really beautiful document with nicely linked table of contents. Sadly, as we see below, the bookmarks are empty and this doesn't happen if the section are titled in Latin alphabet.

[image]

In my case we have Cyrillic sections and I cannot see them bookmarked. Can someone suggest a way to make them appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `unicode` option either to `\hypersetup` or the `\usepackage[unicode,...]{hyperref}` in order to enable the unicode encoding for bookmarks etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{unicode,colorlinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\toccontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\toccontents

\section{Аааа}

\section{Бббб}

\section{Вввв}

\section{Гггг}

\section{Дддд}

\section{Ееее}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have my best regards, it works.